# Перевод англоязычной темы WP

Tags: wordpress

В покупном англоязычном шаблоне содержится папка "languages" в которой лежит файл "cosine.pot". С помощью программы "Proedit" я сделал перевод и получил два файла перевода "cosine.mo" и "cosine.po". Их загрузил в папку "languages". Теперь там три файла.

В файл "wp-config.php" дописал строку "define( 'WPLANG', 'ru_RU' );".

После всех этих манипуляций перевод всё равно не появился. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто оказалось, надо файлы перевода называть именем, которое соответствует языку желаемого перевода. 
Т.е "ru_RU.mo" и "ru_RU.po". Ну и загрузить их в папку "languages".

Comment: Если вас устраивает полученное решение - нажмите кнопку "принять ответ" (слева от вопроса)

Comment: @A K, написано, что только через 2 дня могу принять свой ответ. А так да, обязательно нажму как только смогу.